# How to create an object or associative array with puppeteer evaluate or eval methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, puppeteer, eval, evaluate

I can easily get some single attribute from set of selectors, but cannot create some sort of object or associative array with some "key" and "value".

This works with 2 attributes

```
const kefs = await page.$$eval("div[data-event-treeid]", msgs =>
  msgs.map(msg => {
    return {
      name: msg.getAttribute("data-event-treeid"),
      textMessage: msg.innerText,
    };
  })
);
console.log("kefs", kefs);
```

but I cannot get something like `kefs['data-event-treeid']=innerText`

```
const kefs = await page.$$eval('div[data-event-treeid]', (msgs) => 
  msgs.map((msg[msgs.getAttribute('data-event-treeid')]) => {
    return {
      textMessage: msg.innerText
    }
  })
);
console.log('kefs', kefs);
```

So I want to get:

```
kefs = {"111": "Sometext", "222": "SomeOtherText"}
```

Where keys 111 and 222 are values of 'data-event-treeid' attributes

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. Can you [edit] the post to share a sample expected output and sample HTML structure, or the page itself? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. What sort of syntax is `kefs=[{111}="Sometext",{222}="SomeOtherText"]`? Do you mean `kefs = {"111": "Sometext", "222": "SomeOtherText"}`? Can you provide the input HTML?

Comment: Yes.. sorry. You syntax is right.
The HTML structure doesn't matter. I need just some general example of how to return not an array with list of values, but as key->value style. Thanx

Comment: also tried 
      const kefs = await page.$$eval('div[data-event-treeid]', elements => elements.map(
        element => element[element.getAttribute('data-event-treeid')].innerText)
      );
      console.log('kefs', kefs);

no succcess

Comment: Sorry, I still can't tell what you're asking. Where is the key and value coming from? Can you pick the example and show the output? Are you looking for `Object.fromEntries(await page.$$eval("div[data-event-treeid]", msgs => msgs.map(msg => [msg.getAttribute("data-event-treeid"), msg.textContent])));`?

Comment: The key should come from .getAttribute("data-event-treeid") and the value from .innerText

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @ggorlen
It works for me with

```
const kefs = Object.fromEntries(
  await page.$$eval("div[data-event-treeid]", msgs =>
    msgs.map(msg => [
      msg.getAttribute("data-event-treeid"),
      msg.innerText,
    ])
  )
);
console.log("kefs", kefs);
```

Comment: this also works

```
const kefs = await page.$$eval('div[data-event-treeid]', elements => elements.map(element => [element.getAttribute("data-event-treeid"),element.innerText]));
console.log('kefs', kefs);

```